# Increment Int onClick

Tags: java, android

Noob Android developer here.

I'm creating a basic American Football scorekeeping app for Android. I am trying to increment a variable value with the clock of a XML button.

For some reason, the variable isn't updated as desired when increment button is clicked. I'm sure I'm missing something basic but can't seem to crack it.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_touchdowns_var"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_touchdowns" />

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/home_touchdown_plus"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="homeTouchdownButtonPlus"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/home_touchdowns_var"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_touchdowns" />



 package com.example.android.scorekeeper;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    int homeScore = 0;
    int homeTouchdowns = 0;
    int homeXtraPoints = 0;
    int homeFieldGoals = 0;

    int visitorScore = 0;
    int visitorTouchdowns = 0;
    int visitorXtraPoints = 0;
    int visitorFieldGoals = 0;


    public void homeTouchdownButtonPlus(View view) {
        homeTouchdowns = homeTouchdowns + 1;
    }

    public void homeTouchdownsButtonMinus(View view) {
        homeTouchdowns = homeTouchdowns - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

Your code is right, but is not completed, you have to call the method `setText` of the TextView to update the view data, and also you have to map the TextView in your code, so your code will be:

```
private TextView textview_home_touchdowns; //TextView where you will see the data

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textview_home_touchdowns = (TextView) //Mapping the TextView
                                   findViewById(R.id.home_touchdowns_var);
}

public void homeTouchdownButtonPlus(View view) {
    homeTouchdowns = homeTouchdowns + 1;
    textview_home_touchdowns.setText(homeTouchdowns+""); //Updating the TextView as String

}

public void homeTouchdownsButtonMinus(View view) {
    homeTouchdowns = homeTouchdowns - 1;
    textview_home_touchdowns.setText(homeTouchdowns+"");
}
```

Thank you [@Martin De Simone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6576875/martin-de-simone) for the correction

Answer (score 1):

@DigaoParceiro is right, you forgot to call the setText(), but if you do it the way he did it it will throw an exception, cause the setText method expects a String not an integer, use this.

```
public void homeTouchdownButtonPlus(View view) {
    homeTouchdowns = homeTouchdowns + 1;
    textview_home_touchdowns.setText(String.valueOf(homeTouchdowns)); //Updating the View
}

public void homeTouchdownsButtonMinus(View view) {
    homeTouchdowns = homeTouchdowns - 1;
    textview_home_touchdowns.setText(String.valueOf(homeTouchdowns));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried those corrections and I'm still getting an exception. Java 9 to clarify.

Comment: Then post the logcat